# How to solve Permission denied on Docker Symfony 6

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I'm just starting to learn how to use docker.
In this context I've been trying to Dock my Symfony application recently.
I've set up a configuration that I think is pretty basic.
But unfortunately, when I launch the server, i come across an error 500 that's quite ... important,

I can't even put everything it contains because it takes up so much space.

[image]

Just to clarify, I first build the image which once done, I associate the generated image in the docker-compose.yml file and then I launch the container.
You can find my website repo at this [address](https://github.com/MrMarrant/mrmarrant_website) if you want to look at the configuration.

I tried to find the reason of the error, i focused on the first lines of the errors, because the indicated path seems inconsistent, but impossible to modify with the methods i used.

I suspect the error comes from a misconfiguration of my `apache.conf` file, but the path seems correct, so I don't know.

Here are the files used for my docker configuration :

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.2-apache

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions gd xdebug

RUN curl -sSk https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --disable-tls && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apt update && apt install -yqq nodejs npm

COPY . /var/www/

COPY ./docker/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

RUN cd /var/www/ && \
    composer install && \
    npm install --force && \
    composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle && \
    composer require symfony/dotenv && \
    npm run build

WORKDIR /var/www/

EXPOSE 80
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-15}-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-symfony}
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw

  app:
    image: sha256:6ffb6a8bd9083d4f5f8723a75c216c926669aafe29000886fd071f580eecf529
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://symfony:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:5432/app?serverVersion=15&charset=utf8
  
volumes:
  database_data:
```

**apache.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/public
    DirectoryIndex /index.php

    <Directory /var/www/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I'll keep looking on my own and, of course, i'll come back and explain if i've found where the error came from.

I'd like to thank anyone who tries to help me sort out my error, and I wish you all a good evening.

Comment: error 500 is normally a PHP Error. A catch all that basically means something fairly serious went wrong. Look in your error log for more details

Comment: `/var/www/var/log/dev.log` doesn't have the correct permissions.. use `chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/` in the Dockerfile to set the correct file ownership but if this is supposedly meant for production, I would be using a different user than root!

Comment: @Jaquarh Well, it change nothing even with the permission.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have a few "CRITICAL" requests, but there are a lot of them.

Comment: Did you rebuild your container with the `--build` option?

Comment: @Jaquarh Yes ofc, i had the same result unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Dockerfile you can replace `COPY . /var/www/` with `COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/` and then switch to the correct user with `USER www-data` at the end just before `WORKDIR /var/www/`.

By default docker runs with root privileges so by doing this you change the ownership of the files to the webserver user and then switch to it when the container starts (you do all the other steps as root though). If your webserver uses a different user change `www-data` to that specific user.

You final Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM php:8.2-apache

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions gd xdebug

RUN curl -sSk https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --disable-tls && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apt update && apt install -yqq nodejs npm

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/

COPY ./docker/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

RUN cd /var/www/ && \
    composer install && \
    npm install --force && \
    composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle && \
    composer require symfony/dotenv && \
    npm run build

USER www-data

WORKDIR /var/www/

EXPOSE 80
```

If this doesn't work you can just enter the container at runtime with exec and run `chown -R www-data:www-data var/` but depending on how you mount your files that fix may only be temporary until the next container restart.

Comment: The edit of the Dockerfile work perfectly, thank you again for your reply, and have a great day